# Почему не работает SQL запрос сравнения переменной и значения в БД

Tags: php, sql, база-данных

Есть вот такой код:

```
var_dump($link);
        $query="SELECT * FROM `".$mysql_table."` WHERE `code`=".$link;
        $sql_result=mysql_query($query);
        var_dump($sql_result);
        $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result);
```

Пример: `$link: 3u`, в столбце `code` есть такое значение, однако `var_dump($sql_result);` возвращает `bool(false)`. 
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем ошибка.

Comment: Предоставьте, пожалуйста, код, который записывает значения в $mysql_table

Comment: $query="UPDATE `".$mysql_table."` SET 
                `code`='".$link_short."' WHERE `link_id`='".$row['link_id']."'";
                mysql_query($query);

Comment: $query="INSERT INTO `".$mysql_table."` SET
                    `link_hash`='".$link_hash."',
                    `link_url`='".mysql_real_escape_string($link_url)."'";
                mysql_query($query);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Для запросов SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN и других запросов,
>   возвращающих результат из нескольких рядов, mysql_query() возвращает
>   дескриптор результата запроса (resource), или FALSE в случае ошибки. [Официальная документация](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-query.php)

Ошибка в том, что любые текстовые значения должны быть в кавычках, а оно у вас передается как название колонки и соответственно MySQL не может найти такую колонку в таблице и кидает ответ, что запрос ошибочный. Вот так верно (но не совсем):

```
$query="SELECT * FROM `".$mysql_table."` WHERE `code`='".$link."'";
$sql_result=mysql_query($query);
if (!$sql_result) {
    die('Неверный запрос: ' . mysql_error());
}
$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result);
```

А вообще не в коем случае **не вздумайте** использовать устаревшее расширение mysql и подставлять подобным способом параметры, вы обрекаете себя на мучения связанные с возможностью взлома и отсутствием поддержки в будущих версиях. Ведь, если параметр link приходит от пользователя, я как пользователь могу немного изменить ваш запрос (подробнее читайте: SQL-инъекции) и получить уже данные которые нужны мне. Если конечно вы заранее не делаете проверку типов и т.д.

Правильно строить запрос через PDO или MySQLi c использованием именованных параметров, которые предотвращают глобальное изменение запроса. Пример через PDO:

```
try {

    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE code = :code';
    $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $sth->execute([':code' => $link]);
    $result = $sth->fetchAll();

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. У меня есть перевод всех перевод в строковый тип, поэтому за безопасность я не волнуюсь.